# Average pointer position in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I'm fiddling around with pointers, and as an example, the code:

```
int foo = 25;
int * bar = &foo;
cout << (unsigned long int) bar;
```

outputs something around `3216952416` when I run it.

So why does this code output such a low number, or even a negative number, when I run it?

```
int total = 0, amount = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ )
{
    int foo = 25;
    int * bar = &foo;

    total += (unsigned long int) bar;
    amount++;
}

cout << "Average pointer position of foo: " << total / amount << endl;
```

It's probably something simple...

Comment: How big a value can `int` store on your system?

Comment: That loop is pretty pointless - it's almost guaranteed `foo` will always occupy the exact same position in memory in each iteration.

Comment: For storing pointers as integers, prefer the type `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, variable addresses (which are a pointer's value) are unsigned. You are using signed integer to make your calculation. It explain that the range is shifted, and negative values can occurs. Secondly you are certainly overflowing when using

```
total += (unsigned long int) bar;
```

, so any value is possible.

Your cast is useless, because the type of total is `int`. There will be another implicit cast performed.

You can try to change the type of `total` to unsigned long int but this is not enough. to avoid overflow, ***you need to do the sum of ratio, not the ratio of the sum***

```
double amount = 100000;
double average= 0;

for( int i = 0; i < amount; i++ )
{
    int foo = 25;
    int * bar = &foo;

    average += (((unsigned long int) bar)/amount);
}

cout << "Average pointer position of foo: " << (unsigned long int)average << endl;
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding where I'm assuming that the address will be signed. I am using `(unsigned long int)` to cast the pointer to a number.

Comment: Your cast is useless, because the type of total is int. There will be another implicit cast performed.

Comment: @DuncanNZ But you're storing it `total`, which is a *signed* integer. So the unsigned integer obtained from pointer is immediately converted to a signed one.

Comment: One more question: with your answer, the result is always something like `3213500000`, seemingly rounded a lot. How can I get an exact measure?

Answer (score 1):

`int` cannot store an infinitely large number. When `total` becomes too large to store in an `int`, the value wraps around to the other side of `int`'s range.

On most systems, an `int` variable is held using 32 bits of memory. This gives it a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647.

If your `int` already holds a value of 2147483647 and you add 1, the result will be -2147483648!

So, if you want to calculate the "average pointer value", you need to store your sum in something much larger than `int`, or do your calculations such that you don't need to store the sum of all the pointer values (eg. UmNyobe's answer).

Comment: While your answer usually works in practice on desktop systems, signed overflow is technically Undefined Behvaiour.

Comment: @Angew: Yes, you're correct. For argument's sake though, do you know of any systems where it isn't true?

Comment: No, I don't know such a system. But then again, I've never programmed for anything other than an x86[-64] PC. I believe the embedded/microcontroller folks might know such systems. More importantly, though, the optimiser is allowed to expect signed overflow not to happen. This can kick you on a PC as well.